# Identifying a CALayer on Touch Event (porting functional code to Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, calayer

I'm porting one of my own code snippets from `Objective-C` to Swift, partially as a learning exercise and partially because I am starting a new app.

I have created a `CALayer-derived` class, which contains an array of sublayer `CALayers`.  I am using this as an expanding menu of icons.  The `Obj-C` repository is here if that helps: **https://github.com/lofdev/AnimatedIconDrawer.**

An instance of the class is embedded in a `UIViewController`, and in `Objective-C`, I use this to call the instance, referencing the child sublayer, so that I can do fun things to the instance.

```
 // _drawer is the instance of a CALayer-derived class
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        if ([touches count] == 1) {
            for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
                CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
                point = [[touch view] convertPoint:point toView:nil];
                CALayer *layer = [(CALayer *)self.view.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:point];

                NSInteger clicked_item = [_drawer toggleOpenCloseWithTappedLayer:layer];
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyway, I have ported the code to `Swift`, and I appear to be getting incorrect object references.  Here's the ported code.

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if touches.count > 0 {
            NSLog("Got a touch.")
        }
        for touch in touches {
            let point = touch.locationInView(touch.view)
            let point_view = touch.view?.convertPoint(point, toView: nil)

        //  This line does not work properly... my guess
            let point_layer = CALayer(layer: view.layer.presentationLayer()!).hitTest(point_view!)

            let clicked_item = drawer.toggleOpenCloseWithTappedLayer(point_layer!)
        }
    }
```

I assume I'm doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Can I assume this is pointer-related.

Any help will be appreciated.  And, please be gentle.  I'm new to `Swift`.

Thanks,

Comment: Try `let point_layer = (view.layer.presentationLayer() as? CALayer)?.hitTest(point_view!)`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
let point_layer = CALayer(layer: view.layer.presentationLayer()!).hitTest(point_view!)
```

With:

```
let point_layer = CALayer(layer: (self.view.layer.presentationLayer()?.hitTest(point_view!))!)
```

Late

Answer (score 0):

> Swift 5.x

The below solution works for me.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    guard let point = touch?.location(in: view) else {
        return
    }
    
    guard let layer = self.view.layer.hitTest(point) as? CAShapeLayer else {
        return
    }
}
```